# netstats shows my own server is hitting a server its not supposed to know about

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ddos, netstat, exploit

On AWS I have a few dedicated servers that do image processing, and they seem to get high traffic and fail.

When running

```
netstat -ntu | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

I get that the most active IP is an IP of an nginx load balancer server that is not supposed to route traffic to these servers.

Does it mean that my servers are exploited in some way? How can I tell what is the traffic reason and check the load balance server (nginx over ubuntu)?

Comment: @peterh And what are "Wetstats"?